# Definition of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

A subset $S \subseteq \Bbb R$ is an interval if whenever $a,b \in S$ and $a \lt x \lt b$ we have $x \in S$.

How do I write this definition precisely using quantifiers?

I tried writing it,but it didn't seem satisfactory as the negation of the statement didn't seem meaningful.

(I only have background of basic real analysis)

Comment: Please share with us what you tried writing.  Maybe we can help you see why it didn't work and how to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: With the help of answers here I define it as follows:A subset S or R is an interval if for all a,b in S we have [a,b] is a subset of S.

Comment: So negation would be-A subset S of R is not an interval if there exists a,b in S such that [a,b] is not a subset of S

Comment: Do **not** use "if" for definitions **if** you want to get the logic right! ∀S⊆ℝ ( S is an interval ⇔ ... ). Use "iff" or "if and only if".

Answer (score 1):

I think you were very precise in your wording in the question, but using quantifies, $S \subseteq \Bbb R$ is an interval if
$$(\forall a,b \in S)(\forall x \in \Bbb R)((a<x) \land (x<b) \implies x\in S).$$

Comment: I agree with this,but how do I negate this?

Comment: @shashank Recall that $A \implies B$ is equivalent to $\lnot A \lor B$. So, using De Morgan,$$(\exists a, b \in S)(\exists x \in \Bbb R)((a < x) \land (x < b) \land \lnot (x \in S)).$$In other words, there is some point between points in your set that does not belong to your set; that’s what it means to not be an interval.

Comment: Thanks!I was Slightly with the notation,now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it a little differently than the other answers.  I'd write that $S \subseteq \Bbb R$ is an interval if and only if:

$$\exists u \exists v~(u \in S \land v \in S \land u \neq v) \land \forall a \forall b \forall x~((a \in S \land b \in S \land a \lt x \land x \lt b) \Rightarrow x \in S).$$

This guarantees that $S$ has at least two distinct points and that any point between two points of $S$ is also in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

What you said translates to $a, b \in S, a < x < b \implies x \in S$. I might state it as $a, b \in S \implies [a, b] \subseteq S$.

Comment: With the help of answers here I define it as follows:A subset S or R is an interval if for all a,b in S we have [a,b] is a subset of S.                                                                      So negation would be-A subset S of R is not an interval if there exists a,b in S such that [a,b] is not a subset of S.